# Fetch API always returning a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code where I am calling an api

```
    const fetchToken = async () => {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/getRedisData", 
      {
        key: process.env.AUTH_TOKEN_NAME!,
      });
      console.log(response); // this returns what I expect it to return
      return response;
    };
```

Then I am calling the function like this.

```
    fetchToken();
```

Now, this function works just fine. But when I try to save the data of this response like the following.

```
    token = fetchToken().then((r) => r);
```

It returns a promise and it never resolves. What is happening and how do I wait until this promise resolves. I just need to wait and get the data. Thanks in advance.

#### I updated this question.

Let's suppose I have the following object.

```
    const authMachine = createMachine<toggleAuth>({
      id: "auth",
      initial: "unauthenticated", // I want to chage this value based on token
      context: {
        //
      },
      states: {
        //
      },
    });
```

Now I want to update the initial property based on if I am getting a token or not. Right now I am doing something like this.

```
    initial: token ? "authenticated" : "unauthenticated"
```

So what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `async` functions return a promise.  So your `fetchToken()` function will always return a promise.  The resolved value of that promise will be whatever value you return from the `fetchToken()` function body.

So, the caller of `fetchToken()` has to use `await` or `.then()` to get that resolved value.  There is no free lunch with `async/await`.  It's still asynchronous.  `await` gives you synchronous-like behavior inside the function, but not outside the function.

To explain a little further.  As `fetchToken()` executes, as soon as it hits the first `await`, it immediately suspends further execution of the function body and then immediately returns an unresolved promise back to the caller.  The caller then continues to execute and the caller has to use `.then()` or `await` to know when the body of `fetchToken()` is actually done and what its final returned value is.

Then, sometime later, the promises you used `await` on inside of `fetchToken()` will resolve or reject and when the JS interpreter is back to the event loop, then it will continue executing the rest of the body of `fetchToken()` after the `await`.  When it finally gets to the end of the function body or encounters a `return` statement, then it resolves the promise that was previously returned and the caller that is using either `await` or `.then()` will get notified that it is done and will be given the final return value as the resolved value of that promise.  The caller can then process that final value and do its thing.

So, you probably want to be using something like this to get the final value or the error:

```
fetchToken().then(token => {
    console.log(token);
    // use the token value here
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
// you cannot use the token value here
```

If the call to `fetchToken()` itself is inside an `async` function, then it can use `await` also:

```
try {
    let token = await fetchToken();
    console.log(token);
    // use the token value here
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: I am not inside an async function. Now is there a way to not execute the other line of code until data fetching is complete. Because right now if I save the function it returns a promise first and I don't want that.

Comment: @Pranta - Nope, you can't block execution.  You have to use `.then()` or `await` to get the value out of the promise.  That's how Javascript works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in an `async` function, you can just `await` it to get the data.

```
const token = await fetchToken();
console.log(token);
// do other stuff with token
```

If you aren't, then you need to do everything you want done with the token in your `then` method. This is because you are calling an `async` method and without the ability to `await` it. The execution will just continue. The `then` function is the callback that happens when your `async` method completes successfully.

```
fetchToken().then(token => {
  console.log(token)
  // do other stuff with token
});
```

Comment: I am not inside an async function. Now is there a way to not execute the other line of code until data fetching is complete. Because right now if I save the function it returns a promise first and I don't want that.

Comment: You can't, that's why you have to put the code you want to use with the data inside the `then` function. There is no way to wait for that data to complete before continuing without using an `async` function