# Promise Pending

Tags: javascript, promise

Why does this function not wait for the promise to be answered?
How would a correct application of the async / await principles be?

**My Code**

```
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({});


const getClient = async function () {
  
  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://reqbin.com/echo/get/json`,
    headers: { 
    },
    data : data
  }

  const res = await axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  return res
}
console.log(getClient())
```

**TERMINAL**

```
Promise { <pending> }
{ success: 'true' }
```

Comment: `console.log(getClient().then(response => console.log(response))`

Comment: Full explanation here: [Fetch api always returning promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65165098/fetch-api-always-returning-a-promise/65165320#65165320) as all `async` functions always return a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` is by itself a promise, so it's execution always resolves a promise.

You can handle it like a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (if you read the article you will learn a lot about how async programming works in javascript), so you have 2 options:

Or when you run this function inside another `async/await` function, use the keyword `await`

```js
async run () { 
 console.log(await getClient())
} 
run()
```

Or using the word `then` like for axios.

```
getClient().then((client) => console.log(client))
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this function not wait for the promise to be answered?

Because you aren't awaiting it.

> How would a correct application of the async / await principles be?

```
console.log(await getClient())
```

NB: Requires an environment with top-level `await` or being moved into an `async` function. You could use `getClient().then(value => console.log(value))` instead.